# cannot GET error 404 on reload?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

my react router is working fine with dev env, this is what I did in webpack dev server:

```
historyApiFallback: {  
  index: 'index.html',
}
```

so in production mode I wanted to do the same, I did it in express like this:

```
const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html')
const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'))

  app.use('/public', publicPath)
  app.use('/graphql', graphQLHTTP(async (req) => {
    let { user } = await getUser(req.headers.authorization); 
    if(!user) {
      user = 'guest'
    }
    return { 
      schema, 
      pretty: true,
      graphiql: true,
      context: {
        user,
      }
    }
  })); 

app.get('/', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) });
```

I did not change anything with react-router-dom so I am am assuming the error is in my express config. so what's the equivalent of historyApiFallback in production mode? below is my webpack bundle config:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
```

in my html I reference the bundle like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
```

I think a have the right config but when I reload I get cannot GET Error 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this line to your app:

```
app.get('*', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) });
```

Or you should use this package better: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

You should read more about `history` mode:

To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g. http://oursite.com/user/id. Beautiful!

Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client-side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly.

Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in. Beautiful, again!

Comment: this works, how did using '*' work while '/' did not?

Comment: I updated my answer! And if you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark.